# C# - How to display subdata of specific member?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2016

I have a database with two tables, one for login and another one for games bought. I created a session for login and now I'm having trouble displaying all the rows of this specific customer. I can view the table relationship from MS Access, but I don't know how to display them in labels.

Here's my coding:

```
OleDbDataReader myReader = null;
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from new_table, games where new_table.MemberID='" + Session["New"] + "'", con);

myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    label_id.Text = (myReader["MemberID"].ToString()); //welcome user
}


OleDbDataReader myReader2 = null;
OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("select * from new_table, games where '" + Session["New"] + "' = games.custID", con);

myReader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

if (myReader2.HasRows)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(myReader2);

    label1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["gameTitle"].ToString();
    label2.Text = "$" + Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[0]["gamePrice"]).ToString("N2");
    label3.Text = "$" + Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[0]["gameDisc"]).ToString("N2");
    label4.Text = dt.Rows[2]["gameTitle"].ToString(); 
    label7.Text = dt.Rows[4]["gameTitle"].ToString();
}
```

My problem here is that if I set `dt.Rows[3]` it shows error `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 3.`. I'm still a beginner in C# sorry if this was posted before. Sorry for my bad english, it is not my first language.

Comment: is it correct that you want to display all games that bought by a customer?

Comment: @grepLines yup. but I'm not sure how to. there are few rows with the same game title but they are in different rows bought by different customers..

Comment: can I have the column names for your `games` table? what's `new_table`?

Comment: @grepLines for `new_table` , MemberID, MemberPW, MemberName. for `games`, gameTitle, gamePrice, gameDisc, custID.. custID is the foreign key. MemberID in `new_table` is the primary key. `new_table` is the customer login and details

Comment: do you have `MemberID` in your `games` table?

Comment: nope. I only have `custID` in `games` table, the data in this column is same as `MemberID` in `new_table`

Comment: Can u check whether `dt` has more than 4 rows via debugging?

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed hi, i'm not very sure how to do that, but in my games table there are 4 rows, 3 of which bought by customer A and one bought by customer B..

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
   string query = "select * from (games 
          inner join new_table on games.custID = new_table.MemberID)
          where new_table.MemberID = '" + Session["New"] + "'";
```

Comment: thanks for the help, this is the error i get.. Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in FROM clause.

Comment: MemberID is a type `int`?

Comment: can you try this please, to see if it throws exception: `select * from games`

Comment: no exception, but i tried 2 different customers login and both displaying same games bought (from the same row coz I set `dt.Rows[0]`,`dt.Rows[2]`, and `dt.Rows[4]`

Comment: so only your dt.Rows[3] doesn't work, but rows[2] and rows[4] are fine?

Comment: I edited my query and not sure if it will make any difference, hope that get rid of the exception

Comment: i still get the same exception.. `Syntax error in FROM clause.` at this line with `myReader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();`

Comment: @hj_chua I edited the query again by adding the parenthesis.

Comment: i'm getting this now `Syntax error in JOIN operation.` @___@

Comment: sorry, I'm mostly use MS SQL, which is slightly different, but I think we are getting there. 
Ok, I edited it again, adding `inner `.

Comment: no prob, i'm glad you're trying :) it worked now, but the labels aren't displaying anything from rows..

Comment: do you mean that there is no row available?

Comment: yup, i think so. i'm still using `dt.Rows[0]`, [2], and [4]. my query before this displayed the rows but now it's not displaying anything..

Comment: ok, can you remove the third line in my query, so you get  ->
string query = "select * from (games inner join new_table on games.custID = new_table.MemberID);

Comment: still the same sadly :(

Comment: do you see any custID in your games table, that has the same value in your new_table. I'm just wondering if there is any record in the two tables that has the same ID

Comment: nope.. double checked, i reused my previous query, now the problem I have is that `dt.Rows[2]` and `dt.Rows[3]` are displaying the same row....

Comment: and if the 5th row is empty, it gives error saying there is no row at that position, how do I use `if` statement to detect if the row is empty? `if (dt.Rows[5] == null)`?

Comment: to get the number of rows, `dt.Rows.Count`

Comment: thanks alot :) it worked, but now the rows are repeating, what should I do? The `Rows[0]` and `Rows[1]` are repeating for `Rows[2]` and `Rows[3]` and so on

Comment: oh this could be the query issue. Did you use the your original query? Do you mean Rows[0] = Rows[1] = Rows[2] = Rows[3], Can you show the values for those rows?

Comment: nope I have 10 labels, but there's only 3 rows so the results show 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1.. infinite loop.. same when I add and remove data. 1212121212 or 1234123412